# Error while declaring procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, case, isnull

When I run this query

it returns me a count of null values of the column country

```
(select
    sum(case 
        when (country IS NULL) then 1 
        else 0 END)
    as 'null_flag'
from city)
```

whereas when I try to add the same code in a procedure like this

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE get_null_flags (col_name VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
    (select
        sum(case 
            when ',[' + col_name + ']' IS NULL then 1 
            else 0 END)
        as 'null_flag'
    from city)
    
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

It throws an error saying

```
Query 1 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 10
```

Note: I am using MySQL Ver 8.0.28
I have installed this version via Homebrew. I also have an older version of Mysql ie: 5.7
and I switch the versions using this documentation - https://jeanleem6.github.io/2019/05/08/Multiple-MySQL-Versions-with-Homebrew/

Comment: What's wrong with `select count(*) from city where country is null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a semi-colon after the query. I.e.:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE get_null_flags (col_name VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
(select
    sum(case 
        when ',[' + col_name + ']' IS NULL then 1 
        else 0 END)
    as 'null_flag'
from city);

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

By the way, you don't need to put the query inside a parenthesis.